# OPENING FACEBOOK THROUGH ANDROID APP

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i want to open facebook through other android app, not via its official app nor via browser. i want it to be opened within my app. can i do it only by using its API? or is there any other way? if its possible through API, can anybody tell me some ways to do it? please help me guys.. thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hello. First, it would be nice if you use "I" instead of "i". What do you mean by "Open Facebook"? Do you mean the user's main page?

Comment: Sorry about the i. Yes the user's main page. just like it opens in its official fb app. on click of a button i want to open facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Punith you can use this code for open the Facebook  on our device

`

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("facebook://facebook.com/inbox"));
                startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thanks ankit, but will it open the facebook page inside the app in which im calling it? im new to both stackover flow and android.

Comment: and i want to fetch the whole facebook page when i login to facebook via other android app.

Comment: The code which you gave is opening facebook page in its official app buddy. I want it to be opened inside my android app. not through official app, nor through browser. please help me

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Facebook developers, login there. Create a project there by mention your app name, redirect url. This will generate a client Id and secret for you. Then all you have now, mention this client Id , secret and redirect url in your app and you can now access through Facebook in your app.

Comment: thanks for the reply @amayra. I have done all this things. i have learnt how to fetch my facebook name in my android app but i want to fetch the whole facebook page inside my app in real time. can you help me please.

Comment: Dear, the third party integration doesn't provide you to the full access of their app. They only provide you the basic info.

Comment: But its working on IOS apps!!? are they providing the full access on IOS apps? do you have any info about that sir.